# Blender 3.0 Missing "Translate" Options

Tags: edit-mode

In older versions of blender, there were more options for translating (using the default "G" hotkey) than there appears to be in the current version.

[image]

How do I get these back?  Particularly the axis constraint checkboxes.  I use those very often to quickly check how subtle movements affect things on certain axis and how they compare to other axis to simply entering '0.0' as a value after the fact isn't acceptable.

Edit: To Clarify, I know how to constrain the axis being affected during movement, I need to be able to do this after the fact, like you could in older versions of Blender.

Comment: you can constraint axis by pressing "g", then pressing x or y or z. if you want to constrain on two axes, such as the x and y axes, you can do Shift + Z. What do you mean by "how they compare to other axis to simply entering '0.0' as a value after the fact isn't acceptable."

Comment: I know how to do that, I need to be able to change the locked axis after the fact, and be able to switch between them (which is why entering 0 for axis I want to be temporarily unaffected wouldn't work)

Answer (score 3):

The "additional options" for the move (<kbd>G</kbd>) shortcut are in the *Operator Panel* (bottom left) after you perform the operation. There are also transform/translation statistics and options in the Item Tool Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), and the *Object Data Properties* (right side tab). As for the constraints, as *Gunt.r* mentioned in the comments, axis are restricted by pressing the letter key of the axis after G (move) - you can exclude an axis by holding shift before pressing its letter. Axis constrained movement can also be aided by holding in the middle mouse button (click the wheel) as you move:

[image: Transform]

Comment: I know how to use the hotkey.  I am asking how to get the apparently removed options back.  I need to be able to constrain the axis AFTER the initial move, not during.  I would just use the hotkeys in those cases